# Mysql derived table order by

Tags: mysql, derived-table

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `smp_data_log`
WHERE Post_id = 1234 AND Account_id = 1306
ORDER BY Created_time DESC
```

I get 7 rows back including entries with the following Created_times:

1) 1424134801

2) 1424134801

3) 1421802001

4) 3601

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM `smp_data_log` ORDER BY Created_time DESC) AS mytable
WHERE Post_id = 1234 AND Account_id = 1306
GROUP BY Post_id
```

I am would expect to see 1424134801 come back as a single row - but instead I am seeing 3601?? I would have thought this would have returned the latest time (as its descending). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.  And this is well documented in MySQL.  You are using an extension, where you have columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by` -- a very bad habit and one that doesn't work in other databases (except in some very special circumstances allowed by the ANSI standard).

Just use `join` to get what you really want:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM smp_data_log l JOIN
     (select post_id, max(created_time) as maxct
      from smp_data_log
      group by post_id
     ) lmax
     on lmax.post_id = l.post_id and lmax.maxct = l.created_time;
```

Here is the quote from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html):

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, **so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate**.

Comment: Thank you for your response Gordon. I've added "WHERE l.Post_id = 1234 AND l.Account_id = 1306" and I still get 2 rows returned? The only difference is the Primary ID.

Comment: I see why - its because I have two rows with the same time/date stamp tieing in.

Comment: @Antony . . . If you have an auto-incrementing primary key, you might want to use that instead of `created_time`.

Comment: Cheers for your help :)